# Integrating tfe.EagerVariableStore with tfe.Checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow

`tfe.Checkpoint` seems to require things to be checkpointed to implement `CheckpointableBase` which `EagerVariableStore` doesn't.

What is the right way then to use `EagerVariableStore` to "eagerify" the functional parts of Tensorflow with ability to checkpoint?

Providing some working code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For eagerifying functional code, I'd suggest [`tf.make_template`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_template) rather than `EagerVariableStore` directly. When executing eagerly, this will create a variable store automatically (allowing variable reuse with `tf.get_variable`), and the object `tf.make_template` returns is checkpointable.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def uses_functional_layers(x):
  return tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=1)

save_template = tf.make_template("save_template", uses_functional_layers)
save_checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=save_template)

save_template(tf.ones([1, 1]))
save_template.variables[0].assign([42.])
save_output = save_template(tf.ones([1, 1]))
save_path = save_checkpoint.save('/tmp/tf_template_ckpt')
```

So we make a function which wraps our functional layers / `tf.get_variable` usage, then make a template object out of that with `tf.make_template`, and finally can checkpoint that template object after it has been called once to create its variables.

An advantage of doing it this way is that we get restore-on-create for variables in the template, meaning the template is evaluated with the restored values the first time it is called:

```
import numpy
# Create a second template to load the checkpoint into
restore_template = tf.make_template("save_template", uses_functional_layers)
tf.train.Checkpoint(model=restore_template).restore(save_path)

numpy.testing.assert_allclose(
    save_output,
    restore_template(tf.ones([1, 1])))  # Variables are restored on creation
numpy.testing.assert_equal([42.], restore_template.variables[0].numpy())
```

Nested templates work too. Note that the template object strips its own `variable_scope` from variables created within it, but otherwise uses the full variable names (which may be more fragile than usual object-based checkpointing):

[image: Visualization of the checkpoint graph, using tf.contrib.checkpoint.dot_graph_from_checkpoint]

Looking up variables repeatedly with `tf.get_variable` (done each time the template is evaluated) is also quite slow, which is one reason TensorFlow is moving toward object-oriented Keras-style layers instead of functional layers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a "hackish" way, but works!

The main problem is:

`tfe.EagerVariableStore` doesn't inherit `CheckpointableBase`, hence it can't be saved with `tfe.Checkpoint`

**The big idea is:**

We are going to create a `CheckpointableBase` object that "points" to every variable stored in the `tfe.EagerVariableStore`

#### How to know what are stored in `EagerVariableStore`?

Reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py

It says that `EagerVariableStore` uses `_VariableStore` to store all the variables, via `_store`.

Now, the `_VariableStore` stores the variables in `self._vars` as a dictionary.

If we have a `container = tfe.EagerVariableStore()`, we can get all the variables via `container._store._vars` as a dictionary.

#### How to create a `CheckpointableBase` that points to every variable then?

We will use `tfe.Checkpointable` since it has `__setattr__`.

```
checkpointable = tfe.Checkpointable()
for k, v in container._store._vars.items():
    setattr(checkpointable, k, v)
```

#### How to combine the two?

As we have a `tfe.Checkpoint` for saving, all we need to do is this:

```
saver = tfe.Checkpoint(checkpointable=checkpointable)
saver.save(...)
```

And `saver.restore(...)` to restore.

Your `tfe.EagerVariableStore` need not to be changed, the `checkpointable` after restored via `tfe.Checkpoint` will "replace" the values in `tfe.EagerVariableStore` automigically!